# PHP POST variables missing value when form submission is made from Chrome on a mac

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, macos

I have a php form in a website checkout section that sends an email after the checkout process, and also saves the order in the database. Values entered in one field of the form, which is a text area for comments/instructions, is losing the value entered on submitting the form. The order is being saved correctly, but this field is blank, even if value is entered. 
This is happening only in Chrome, and works perfect on Firefox. 
Any inputs on what could be happening plz ..

Comment: Can you add the relevant code

Answer (score -1):

We need a specific example of your problem.  As written, your question gives us no starting point.  We need an example of the form element and afflicted sub elements.  We also need to know what versions of Chrome, Firefox, and what platform you are working on.

Alternatively, you might consider dropping `print_r($_POST); echo "<p>";` in as the first output when you process the form.  Do it before everything, even your session setup (expect an error to be generated.  Session hates being second.).  If the value is empty here, there is a problem with either how you've constructed the HTML (which is why we need to see it) or with the version of Chrome you're using (which is very unlikely).

If you find that first print_r displays the correct value, you need to move it inch-by-inch along your code path until you discover where the value is lost.